# Download file via POST in one request with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Sometimes when making an HTTP request to download a file (e.g. PDF, XLSX, etc.) from the own webserver, it is necessary to use the HTTP method POST, because it requires dynamic input data. I have been trying different ways to reduce that to one single HTTP request for best performance, but could not succeed.

As JavaScript with the **XMLHttpRequest object (AJAX)** can not "download" files, I guess it requires an HTML workaround. The only working solution I found for that case is generating a **form** element wrapping **input** elements containing the data. I could not find a way how to send **boolean values** via this, as AJAX is able to. That would mean: it is not suitable for a standardizable implementation.

**My question is:** How can I download a file via one POST request which can include boolean values (JavaScript)?

In case it is important: The backend system I use is Ruby on Rails

Comment: Just send the strings "true" or "false" or whatever it is that your server-side code expects. Parameters are always strings in HTTP, whether AJAX or not.

Comment: I tested it and you are right! Thank you for improving my knowledge about the HTTP. Do you want to post it as an answer or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pointy mentioned, boolean values are always translated to strings in HTTP communication. I was wrong about that in my question. That means, converting a JavaScript JSON string or a classic object to an HTML form (then submitting and deleting it) works!

Actually sending an AJAX request and then manually triggering a link click to the generated file has the advantage of being able to use a progressbar.